# Understanding behavior of stellar API result codes

Tags: stellar-sdk, trustline

I am facing a challenge with stellar APIs while transferring funds from one wallet to another. The API fails with status 400 and the result code is 'op_no_trust'. I can verify that the destination wallet has trustline enabled. I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error.

**Stack trace -**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./apis.py", line 188, in transfer_crypto
    response = builder.submit()   File "/home/ubuntu/glitzkoin-blockchain-apis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_base/builder.py", line 784, in submit
    return self.horizon.submit(self.gen_xdr())   File "/home/ubuntu/glitzkoin-blockchain-apis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_base/horizon.py", line 142, in submit
    return check_horizon_reply(reply.json())   File "/home/ubuntu/glitzkoin-blockchain-apis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_base/horizon.py", line 917, in check_horizon_reply
    raise HorizonError('Invalid horizon reply: [{}] {}'.format(reply['status'], reply), reply['status']) stellar_base.exceptions.HorizonError: Invalid horizon reply: [400] {'type': 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed', 'title': 'Transaction Failed', 'status': 400, 'detail': 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details. Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://developers.stellar.org/api/errors/http-status-codes/horizon-specific/transaction-failed/', 'extras': {'envelope_xdr': 'AAAAADqRnBEyRDLb2wdAiIjLxGwDChdQ7kyAsCMXK5pnRWhEAAAAZAI4iNsAAC6QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA+z2lv/0NsRsYLgGr7I4GYtSuRBA8zm0Yr7mwbwuthtcAAAABR1ROAAAAAAAiVgDwZxI0d7JWimI9bs0+GZHDlvHYNnurIQRTdq6PMAAAAAAExLQAAAAAAAAAAAFnRWhEAAAAQNcYSU8baXLTIhNuheBQ/U0G2YXb6YFoeVOUR15UDkEt4zWJhZ2JMEF7YjBgvoXuaiUiw440QgSPb4N0rNz6Vwc=', 'result_codes': {'transaction': 'tx_failed', 'operations': ['op_no_trust']}, 'result_xdr': 'AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAB////+gAAAAA='}}
```